# Why image is not loading in Twig Template?

Tags: php, image, symfony, twig

I want to load every user image in my twig with the following line:

```
<img src="/web/images/users/{{ topic.user.image }}" class="w3-circle" width="100" height="100">
```

And am sure the path is correct. The user avatar is in web/images/users/ and selected image. Where can be the problem then ?

That's displayed:[image]

And That's how i try to upload image file in registration controller:

```
/** @var UploadedFile $file */
                $file = $user->getImageForm();

                $filename = md5($user);

                $file->move(
                    $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/images/users/',
                    $filename
                );

                $user->setImage($filename);
```

Comment: Have you tried `src="web/images/users/{{ topic.user.image }}"....`

Comment: Yes, but still not working

Comment: What does it look like when rendered.

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your web-server probably already point to the web dir, so try simple:

```
<img src="images/users/{{ topic.user.image }}" class="w3-circle" width="100" height="100">
```

Hope this help

NB: You can try debugging dump the value of `topic.user.image` and check in which path the image exists. Then try to locate with your browser and see what happen.

Comment: The problem was that the we-server is already point to the web dir, thanks !